# webbrowser open internet explorer error instead of default browser (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I was suffering from webbrowser internet explorer problem the code worked fine but it opens the internet explorer the simplest solution is to use " https://www " in starting of every url it will always open default browser for everyone hope it helps to many

Answer (score 0):

this code will open your default browser

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.amazon.com/")
```

while this code will open your internet explorer

```
webbrowser.open("amazon.com")
```

simple solution to fix webbrowser internet explorer is to add  https://www in front of every url that you give input

Comment: “amazon.com” isn’t a *URL*, it could as well be a local folder. A complete URL starts with a *scheme*, i.e. “http://”. Not every domain defines a “www” sub domain. In summary, the “http://” is the important part, “www” should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If your default browser is Firefox or Chrome, you can use Selenium.

To install Selenium: Open the command prompt/shell on your system and type: `pip install selenium`

Firefox tutorial: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-firefox/

Chrome tutorial: https://youtu.be/Xjv1sY630Uc

I recommend taking a look at the Selenium for Python documentation if you're using either Firefox or Chrome.

Selenium documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/